# Method to eliminate $x$ between the equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $xy+ l(x + y) + m = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If by eliminating $x$ between the equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $xy+
>  l(x + y) + m = 0$, a quadratic in $y$ is formed whose roots are the
>    same as those of the original quadratic in $x$. Then prove either $a =
>  2l$ & $b = m$ or $b + m = al$.

Initially, I thought of eliminating $x$ but that method seems to be very lengthy. Is there any trick that can help to solve the problem faster?

Comment: Reamark: In the past, this kind of elimination by transforming the initial equation through an homographical change of variable $y= (rx+s)/(tx+u)$ was classical.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861906/quadratic-equation-based-problemprove-either-a-2l-b-m-or-b-m-al?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ are the two solutions, then $y_1, y_2$ are the two solutions of the quadratic in $y$

We have two cases:

1) $x_1 = y_1, x_2=y_2$

This case $x=y$ and the second equation becomes $x^2 + 2lx + m=0$ therefore $2l = a, m=b$

2) $x_1 = y_2, x_2=y_1$

We know $x_1y_1+ l(x_1 + y_1) + m = 0$ Replacing $y_1$ with $x_2$ we get $b -al +m =0$

Comment: Why should the cases hold? Like why should $x_1 = y_1, x_2=y_2$.Can you explain?

Comment: @ZOZ Because the quadratic in y has same  roots  as those of the original quadratic in x. But the  roots of  the quadratic in y are $y_1, y_2$