# Prove that either $a=2l$ and $b=m$ or $b+m=al$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If by eliminating $x$ between the equations $x^2+ax+b=0$ and $xy+l(x+y)+m=0$ then a quadratic in $y$ is formed whose roots are the same as the original quadratic in $x$. Then prove that either $a=2l$ and $b=m$ or $b+m=al$.

It seems a very lengthy process to eliminate $x$. Does anyone know of any shorter method?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861906/quadratic-equation-based-problemprove-either-a-2l-b-m-or-b-m-al?rq=1